# Nginxで、wget からのダウンロードを拒否したい

Tags: centos, nginx

**質問**
Q1.Nginxで、wget からのダウンロードを拒否することは出来ますか？
Q2.Nginxで、指定拡張子のみ、wget からのダウンロードを拒否することは出来ますか？

**分からない点**
・wget からのダウンロード実行を拒否できる？　それとも、wget からのアクセス自体を拒否するしかない？
・wget を「user agent」で拒否することは可能？　wget 使用する際の「user agent」はどうなりますか？

**質問背景**
「.htaccess」で出来ることを、Nginxではどのように設定するか(出来るか)、知りたい

---

2020/7/13
質問文を大幅に修正しました

2020/7/12
「自分以外からダウンロードされないよう」を「ダウンロードされないよう」へ変更しました。

Comment: あなたはどうやってダウンロードするんですか？　それこそ BASIC 認証でも入れておけば十分なのでは？

Comment: "異なる場所" が何を指しているのか曖昧ですし、「あなた」と「あなた以外」を区別するには 774RR さんも挙げているようにユーザー認証に頼るしか無い気がします。

Comment: 典型的な [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) に見えます。邪推すると、真にやりたいのは恐らく **個人的な覚書のオンライン管理** であり、たまたま Nginx の環境があるのでそこで賄えないか…がこの質問になっている気がします。

Comment: このままだと既存の回答と内容が合わなくなるので、今の質問文はロールバックして、新しく質問するべきでは？

Answer (score 3):

まあわざわざ作らなくても Microsoft OneDrive とか Google Drive とかありますし Nginx にこだわることなく柔軟に運用すればよいかと。

Answer (score 3):

これを行うためには、nginx に「自分」と「他人」を認識してもらう必要があります。しかし物理的な自他の差は nginx が認識できる情報ではありません。このため「自分」の定義の方を見直すか、nginx では無いもので管理するかをすることになりでしょう。

「自分」の定義の方を見直す方法としては、たとえば「特定の IP アドレスのみ allow する」という方法はあります。しかしこれはあまり便利ではないでしょう。ノートパソコンを持って別のネットワークから接続したいことはよくあるだろうことを考えると、自分の IP アドレスが常に固定されているという前提はあまり置きたくありません。

他の方法としては nginx レベルでのパスワード認証を使うことも考えられます（パスワードを知っているなら自分、とする）。BASIC 認証や Digest 認証程度の認証能力で満足できるなら一応使えます。

nginx で無いものを使う方法としては、そもそも wget ではなくて ssh を使うようにして、ファイルパーミッションで縛るやり方があります。サーバー上のファイルをユーザー認証付きで読み書きしたいのであれば普通まずは ssh を検討しそうな気がします。

まあしかしここまで書いておいてなんですが、[774RR さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68467/19110)にもあるように、自分だけが見えるファイルをインターネット越しに見えるようにしておきたいだけなのであれば Google Drive 等のサービスを使う方が管理もラクですし便利です。

Comment: 「nginx に「自分」と「他人」を認識してもらう必要があります」。質問時の想定としては、例えば、「.hoge」をserverへFTPでアップロードして、「.hoge」拡張子をWebからダウンロードできないようにしたいです。Webから「.hoge」拡張子へ対しては自分もアクセス不可で構わないです。「FTPからはアクセス可」だけど「Webからはアクセス不可」みたいなことは出来ないですか？

Comment: @re9 "FTPからはアクセス可でwebからはアクセス不可" は、単にwebサーバとして対象のデータを公開しない、で実現できませんか？ / ご自身の中でやりたい事が整理しきれていない印象です。

Answer (score 3):

wgetや他ツールでもUser-Agentが大体変えられるのですが、一般のユーザは、Defaultを使うとしては、`user-agent` による拒否は可能でしょう。

> Wget normally identifies as **‘Wget/version’**, version being the current version number of Wget.

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-user_002dagent

nginxによるUser-Agent拒否：
http://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/block-user-agents-nginx/?replytocom=163615#